# Placing the NSSplitView in the NSPageController and toggling the sidebar, the display is broken

Tags: xcode, operating-system, nssplitview

PageViewController is placed in SplitViewController and TextView is turned into a page.
Consecutive switching will break the size of the pageview or TextView.
AutoResizingMask on all views in the story board.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

source
https://github.com/llscsrl/SplitAndPage

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the collapse of the display by setting the resizable horizontally.

[image]